# URL from WebBrowser Control to FileInfo Method C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a Web Browser Control in a C# Winform Application. I'm loading local files to the WebBrowser Control. I want to pull the information from the file that is currently loaded in the WebBrowser control to a FileInfo Method.

I've tried

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());
```

Throws the error:

```
URI formats are not supported.
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a chicken and egg question.  You already knew the path when you loaded the file into the WebBrowser.  Just don't forget.  Also handles assigning the DocumentText property which doesn't allow you to read back anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [`LocalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx) property of the `Uri` object stored in the `Url` property:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(webBrowser1.Url.LocalPath);
```